# How could I make a solid border that goes round all my form elements?

Tags: html, css

I am asking this question in regards to how I could make a border that goes around all of the elements on my form. I haven't coded in months and I'd be grateful if you could help me, cheers

```css
.form {
 top: 20%;
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 70%;
 border: 8px solid black;
}

.form .username {
 height: 20px;
 width: 180px;
 top: 30px;
 position: absolute;
 padding: 6px;
 margin: 10px;
 margin-left: 53%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.form .password {
 height: 20px;
 width: 180px;
 top: 90px;
 margin-left: 38%;
 position: absolute;
 padding: 6px;
 border-radius: 5px;

}

.form #submit {
 height: 20px;
 width: 70px;
 top: 120px;
 height: 30px;
 position: absolute;
 padding: 6px;
 margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <form action="" method="POST">
  
    <input type="text" placeholder=" Please enter a username" class="username"name="username">
    
    <input type="password" placeholder="please enter your password" class="password" name="password">
    
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
    
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your elements inside your `.form` had position absolute, causing it not to have any height, this is not needed as the parent will control the positon.

```css
.center {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}

.form {
  border: 8px solid black;
}

.form input {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.form .username, .form .password {
  height: 20px;
  width: 180px;
}

.form #submit {
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form center">
  <form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder=" Please enter a username" class="username" name="username">

    <input type="password" placeholder="please enter your password" class="password" name="password">

    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```css
.form{
    width: 250px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-top: 5%;
}
.form input[type="text"], .form input[type="password"] {
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.form input[type="submit"]{
     padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" placeholder=" Please enter a username" name="username">

<input type="password" placeholder="please enter your password" name="password">

<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</div>
```